# What exactly is symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups, symmetry

I mean, I know intuitively what symmetry is.

But if we want to be exact, is it defined as a mapping from an object to itself preserving the structure? Or it is defined as a property that an object has, that is, the object remains unchanged under a set of operations?

Even the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_mathematics) about symmetry provides these two "definitions" one after another. But I cannot help but feel that they are different things. I would say that symmetry is property of invariance under a mapping, not the mapping itself.

For the context, I mainly work with symmetries in terms of groups. (I.e. rotational, reflectional symmetry etc.) Maybe this adds to my confusion, since there is a [symmetric group $S_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) with clear definition and operation, but also [symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) (group of symmetries) which is a group of transformations of a given abstract object that preserve its structure.

In summary, how should be symmetry best defined/described?

Thank you for your insights on this.

May be relevant: [A similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679094/what-exactly-is-meant-by-symmetry) on this forum, describing symmetry as a **condition**.

Comment: The term is overloaded, in a way, so it can denote both of the things that you refer to in your second paragraph.

Comment: There's something deeply mysterious about symmetries (take, for instance, the intoxicating peculiarity of the sporadic groups). To me, a symmetry is an efficient way of storing information. Or equivalently, a hint of unnecessary information. That is to say, If an object has a certain symmetry, we can reconstruct the entirety of the object given only fragments of its data.

Comment: The Wikipedia article looks good to me: it is distinguishing the abstract concept of "symmetry" and the specific concept of "a symmetry".This a common distinction in English: e.g., "language" refers to human speech in general, while "a language" refers to one of English or French or ... (Likewise with "speech" or "therapy" or "science" or ...)

Comment: You might be interested in my MMath dissertation on inverse semigroups & inductive groupoids. There, it describes a wider sense of symmetry than is given by group theory. You can find the document by following the link on my profile.

Comment: Some more examples from physics and mathematics may help to understand what it can be. See for example [mirror symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_symmetry_(string_theory)).

Comment: By the way, the symmetric group $S_n$ is a particular example of the group of symmetries of a set, the set being a collection of $n$ distinct objects, often denoted $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ for convenience.

Comment: @SammyBlack: True, although I find as a pedagogical matter, people have some initial trouble understanding why any permutation is a **symmetry**, without some motivating example like the symmetry of an equilateral triangle, or of a regular tetrahedron, etc.

Comment: From the wiki link: "*Given a structured object X of any sort, a symmetry is a mapping of the object onto itself which preserves the structure.*". So, it seems to me that a "symmetry" is just any element of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$.